# Emulating horizontal inline-block elements but with element heights that can bypass their inline height

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry if I'm wording the title poorly, it's hard to explain succinctly.

Let's say I have a bunch of paragraph elements, each can have a different height, but the same width. They are all styled with `display: inline-block` which means they are all "inline". This is an example of how the HTML/CSS is rendered:

[image: inline-block]

What I want to get is this:

[image]

How can I get elements to take up the unused space above them while still being generated as inline-block?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Are you referring to number 2 in your image? Can you show your html and css?

Comment: I'm referring to the second image http://jsfiddle.net/75jz4afw/2/

Comment: I get you. For that, you would need to implement some javascript. I suggest something like [Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Comment: Adding as answer since I crave the rep :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you would need to implement some javascript. I suggest something like [Masonry.js](http://masonry.desandro.com/)